# Create Notification Hub - REST only (no SDK)

Tags: c#, rest, azure, azureservicebus, azure-notificationhub

For an automated testing service for our iOS apps we need an programmatic way to create Notification Hubs in our Mac build system. I can't use the SDK because it won't run under Mono for unknown reasons relating to timer DLL conflicts so I just want to use "stock" REST APIs if I can.

I see the similar question: [Creating Azure Push Notification Hub Programaticaly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820729/creating-azure-push-notification-hub-programaticaly) but uses the SDK so is not relevant for me.

This API guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223269.aspx says you can do it using REST and SAS tokens. I can't get this to work. However the SDK places the CreateHub operation on the namespace manager - but IT states "Operations on the Service Bus namespace root require certificate authentication" which also doesn't seem to work for me. I followed this ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn170477.aspx ). With the Resource URI being http://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net and the key being "RootManageSharedAccessKey" and our key as well.

All my attempts are generating 401 errors - "InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature"

I could really use a hand holding walkthrough of the process I should use with REST only to create a Notification Hub. What resource URI I should use, what should be in the token, what the namespace maps towith the REST API - etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently introduced a lot of features including NH creation in [open source Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-java-backend). Try it out or just look how is corresponding REST call implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the update - turns out there are a few differences in the sample C# SAS generator on MSDN and yours. Yours works :) I just translated your Java to C# and it's fine now.

Comment: @s-wilkinson any chance you have that C# REST wrapper lying around?

Comment: To be frank using the REST became horrible in C# - they've bumped the SDK a lot since I last used it - so it's probably a lot better now :)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/net/
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net