# Notification Hub Creation Error

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-storage

I am trying to add a notification hub to my asp.net web-api published on azure but it gives me the following error

```
There was an error while creating Notification Hub . {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"The Resource 'Microsoft.NotificationHubs/namespaces/notificationhubs' under resource group 'SS_DB_API_RGRP' was not found."}}
```

Comment: How are you creating it through portal or powershell?

Comment: I am creating it through portal

Answer (score 0):

You should try create service bus azure entity (10-15 from top on old azure portal). And create notification hub in it.

Comment: Can I not just create a notification hub directly??

Comment: You wanna create hub using code or other tools?
I have created notification hub through the azure cli. (+sh and bat for easy work)

Or you can try to create any azure entity programaticaly:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820729/creating-azure-push-notification-hub-programaticaly